# Android Google plus login button style

Tags: android, google-plus, android-styles

I need the long style button for google+ signin in android.

According to the Branding guidelines [here](https://developers.google.com/+/branding-guidelines) there are different styles for the button like long, medium, short etc

I am getting the medium style button with help of the sample app, But I want the long style button.

here is my button `

```
   <com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton
        android:id="@+id/sign_in_button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:visibility="visible" />
```

`

Comment: please post your code here..

Comment: I have added the code for button. but I don't know how can I change the style of this. Thanks in advance

Comment: but why are you change style?

Comment: It will be appreciated if you can help here.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

As the website described there are 3 sized button

1. Icon only       =  SignInButton.SIZE_ICON_ONLY
2. Normal button   =  SignInButton.SIZE_STANDARD
3. Wide button     =  SignInButton.SIZE_WIDE

You can use it like this.

```
gSignInButton = (SignInButton) findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button);
gSignInButton.setOnClickListener(this);
gSignInButton.setEnabled(true);
gSignInButton.setSize(SignInButton.SIZE_WIDE);// wide button style
```

Comment: I want to change the button size in xml not in coding because i am designing the screens for different sizes so that if i change in code it will effect all the screens. So please tell me how to do it in xml coding

Answer (score 12):

You can do it with XML by adding & using the `app` namespace (as they are custom attributes):

```
<com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
      android:id="@+id/sign_in_button"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      app:buttonSize="wide"
      app:colorScheme="dark"
      />
```

Possible attributes values are:

- buttonSize: `"wide", "icon_only" or "standard"`(default)
- colorScheme: `"dark", "light" & "auto"`(default)

Comment: How did you even found out the different value available to this app attributs ?

Comment: I mainly extrapolate from the constant's names and by trying them: https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/SignInButton#constant-summary. But I found a more serious way to find them, from the library aar source file: https://github.com/dandar3/android-google-play-services-base/blob/master/res/values/values.xml.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [setSize](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/SignInButton.html#setSize%28int%29) method of the Signin button to update the size.

For example, in my activity's `onCreate` method:

```
    mSignInButton = (SignInButton) findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button);
    mSignInButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    mSignInButton.setSize(SignInButton.SIZE_WIDE);
```

will change the Sign-In button to be wide.

You can also just use ANY button that is appropriately branded by just using a Button and then using the activity as the button's click handler.

Answer (score 0):

Just make this button visibility View.GONE, make your custom button and send onclick event from your button to SignInButton.performClick()