# Android Google plus login button style in xml

Tags: android, google-plus, android-styles

Is it possible to change the style of the Google+ sing-in button in the layout xml file? According to the Branding guidelines [here](https://developers.google.com/+/branding-guidelines) you have four options.
I know it is possible to do it from code like in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21111914), but I would like to avoid that if possible.

Comment: I don't recommend changing the style of the Google+ button since it may be considered a violation of the guidelines "For buttons that may be rendered by the Publisher, such as the Sharing link, the Publisher must use only the official Google-provided icon or a plain text and link combination. In either case, Publishers must not mislead users as to the purpose of the link." source: https://developers.google.com/+/web/buttons-policy

Comment: I don't want to change the default styling of the button. I just want to change its size according to the branding guidelines.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android Google plus login button style](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21042914/android-google-plus-login-button-style)

Comment: @thepoosh I am asking if this can be done using the layout file. The link you posted is already in the question and solves the issue by using Java code.

Answer (score 1):

As also answered on this other [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21042914/android-google-plus-login-button-style/39051164), you can do it with XML by adding & using the `app` namespace (as they are custom attributes):

```
<com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
      android:id="@+id/sign_in_button"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      app:buttonSize="wide"
      app:colorScheme="dark"
      />
```

Possible attributes values are:

- buttonSize: `"wide", "icon_only" or "standard"`(default)
- colorScheme: `"dark", "light" & "auto"`(default)

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to change the size and some layout aspects, yes, it should be possible in you layout xml. You can refer [here](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/sign-in) and [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/SignInButton.html) for more info;

As an example:

```
<com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton
    android:id="@+id/sign_in_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Comment: Customizing it in the code works very well, but unfortunately you cannot do it directly from the layout file. To do that you need a custom [button](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/sign-in#customizing_your_sign-in_button).